# Does jQuery Extend Create an Empty Object when Target is Undefined

Tags: jquery

Working with the jQuery extend functionality and have run into a case where I am trying to extend a target object that is undefined. I don't get any errors but the source object is not extended as expected. I had assumed that jQuery would create a blank object and extend to that but this does not seem to be the case. I can work around this by creating the empty object my self but I am looking for some confirmation that this is the case with jQuery's extend. I could not find anything in the jQuery Api about the target object being undefined.

EDIT: Sorry I should have included a JSFiddle - [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/RgpDb/) or see the example below. And in doing so need to modify my question. If you look in the fiddle the options object exists, but the property I'm trying to extend to does not exist. This is where my problem is lying. I am guessing jQuery won't create the empty property this way. And I would need to add the property to the object manually?

```
options = {newdata:true};

$("#click").click(function(){
  console.log(options);
  someFunc(options);
});

function someFunc(options) {
  $.extend(options.data, {
    someNewData: true
  });
  console.log(options);
}
```

Comment: I think you approach in testing for the object existence and creating it if not defined is probably best, as I wouldn't think that it would ever be good coding practice to try to operate on something that is not defined.

Comment: It seems like jQuery creates an object appropriately when extending `undefined`: http://jsfiddle.net/7BdeE/1/

Comment: Since you didn't provide any code, i'll make some up. Is this anything like what you are using? http://jsfiddle.net/GTwxy/ it seems to just make it an empty object and continue without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the relevant [jQuery source file](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L270)

```
target = arguments[0] || {};
```

The first aregument sent to `jQuery.extend` is used. If it is falsy or undefined, a new empty object will be created. `target`  is then returned by `jquery.extend`.

If you were to do the following:

```
var target = undefined;
var data = {'hello': 'world'};
jQuery.extend(target, data);
```

`target` would still be `undefined`. If you want to work with a `target` that may be undefined, you have to use `jQuery.extend` like so:

```
var target = undefined;
var data = {'hello': 'world'};
target = jQuery.extend(target, data);
```

Working off your example code, you need to do this:

```
function someFunc(options) {
    options.data = $.extend(options.data, {
        someNewData: true
    });
    console.log(options);
}
```

Note how the return value of `jQuery.extend` is assigned to `options.data`.